# WriteFile function retuns success but not able to view file in file system

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to write the content of unsigned short and unsigned char array content to an .img file. I am using WriteFile method to do the same. it seems like WriteFile function successfully writing the array content to the file but the main problem is i am not able to view that file in file system. Following are the two methods I am using to Write the data to the file.

```
void createImageFile(unsigned short* src,int srcLength,const char* fileName)
 {         
     DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
     unsigned short *dest = new unsigned short[srcLength];
      if(is_file_exist(fileName))
      {
             remove(fileName);
      }
      HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(LPCWSTR(fileName), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
      DWORD e = GetLastError();

      if(hFile)
      {
        memcpy(dest,src,srcLength*sizeof(unsigned short));
        bool b = WriteFile(hFile,dest,srcLength,&dwBytesWritten,NULL);
          if(!b)
          {
              DWORD e = GetLastError();
           }            CloseHandle(hFile);
      }
      if(dest)
      {
          delete[] dest;
          dest = NULL;
      }
 }

void createImageFile(unsigned char* src,int srcLength,const char* fileName)
     {         
         DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
         unsigned short *dest = new unsigned short[srcLength];
          if(is_file_exist(fileName))
          {
                 remove(fileName);
          }
          HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(LPCWSTR(fileName), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
          DWORD e = GetLastError();

      if(hFile)
      {
        memcpy(dest,src,srcLength*sizeof(unsigned short));
        bool b = WriteFile(hFile,dest,srcLength,&dwBytesWritten,NULL);
          if(!b)
          {
              DWORD e = GetLastError();
           }            CloseHandle(hFile);
      }
      if(dest)
      {
          delete[] dest;
          dest = NULL;
      }
 }
```

I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. I am not able to view those files on the specified path. Can somebody please help me in this?
Another thing I want to highlight is, the above code is the part of unmanaged code and supposed to be reside in the dll.

Comment: You should check the return from `CreateFile` against INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Comment: `CloseHandle` the file when you're finished with it. You'r leaking the file handle unless you *fail* to write to it. In the process, the file is open with no sharing mode specified and write-mode-only, so until your process dies, no joy on anyone getting that file again. And your cut-paste solution for a char vs short array isn't going to fly well, You're copying `srcLength` ushorts from a `char *` buffer of `srcLength` size. Thats going to be at least a 2X overhead and likely UB in the process.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i tried that approach too. it is not returning Invalid handle.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just cast `fileName` to a wide string.

Don't forget to close the file.

`CreateFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` not zero on failure. So, your error checking condition is incorrect.

Copying `src` to `dest` is quite unnecessary. Nor do you need to set the pointer to `NULL` after deletion.

Also, you have a race condition between `remove(fileName)` and `CreateFile`. You don't need to remove — setting `dwCreationDisposition` is sufficient.

---

The whole function could be written as:

```cpp
void createImageFile(unsigned short* src, int srcLength, const char* fileName)
{
    using namespace std;
    ofstream stream(fileName, ios_base::binary | ios_base::trunc);
    stream.write(src, srcLength * sizeof(unsigned short));
}
```

Comment: Stupidest mistake ever. in I should have used TEXT() instead of LPCWSTR in `CreateFile` function. as the filename/path was given in wrong manner the files were getting created at the path from where the application is running and I was looking the files at the wrong place. Thanks a lot for help guys...

Comment: You should not use TEXT either. This is a macro for string literals only.

Comment: And I would appreciate it, if you accepted the answer, if it helped. :)

Comment: Thanks for the above code. tested it and seems to be working fine.